# timezone aware cron jobs (adjust for DST)

Tags: cron, timezone

I have a need to download files from all over the world to the same server. The files become available at the same time each day in the local timezone. The challenge is daylight savings time. Because different countries adjust on different days, and some don't do DST at all, the offset between any 2 timezones changes throughout the year. So it is not possible to convert everything into a single timezone. Is there a way to handle this with cron? Or something similar to cron?

I already tried this and it does **not** do what I want:

```
TZ=Asia/Tokyo
05 15 * * * echo $(date) JAPAN >> /tmp/crontest1.txt 2>&1
TZ=Europe/London
05 15 * * * echo $(date) LONDON >> /tmp/crontest2.txt 2>&1
TZ=America/New_York
05 15 * * * echo $(date) NY >> /tmp/crontest3.txt 2>&1
TZ=America/Denver
05 15 * * * echo $(date) DENVER >> /tmp/crontest4.txt 2>&1
```

everything runs at 15:05 in the timezone of the server and the output is

```
Fri Mar 24 04:05:01 JST 2017 JAPAN
Thu Mar 23 19:05:01 GMT 2017 LONDON
Thu Mar 23 15:05:01 EDT 2017 NY
Thu Mar 23 13:05:01 MDT 2017 DENVER
```

so while each process runs with the TZ value set correctly it runs at the time of the main server. I need something that adjusts the start time for DST.

Comment: Not sure you can do this that way. What about launching a script hourly with timezone in parameter and check in your script if it's the good hour regarding the timezone ?

Comment: Don't ever set up a server in anything but UTC because otherwise it causes problems such as your's. http://yellerapp.com/posts/2015-01-12-the-worst-server-setup-you-can-make.html

Comment: If you can't change these servers to UTC, consider changing your approach from pull to push.

Comment: The server is in UTC, but that doesn't help. It's gathering data from around the world from 3rd parties that don't use UTC. So the process launcher still needs to be aware of timezones and DST.

Comment: I am not sure this is possible with normal cron implementation, but seems there is a [cron-utils issue filed](https://github.com/jmrozanec/cron-utils/issues/213) for a similar functionality ...